Closing/killing an appimage
I'm running an appimage version of Roland MT-32 Emulator to get midi sound on RetaroArch's PX68K core, under Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS.
I got it here, and it works as well as the .deb packaged version.
I include it on a script that launchs well retroarch + core, but when I exit retroarch the system freezes. I do not find a correct way to close/kill the appimage. I tried sudo killall MT-32_Emulator-x86_64.AppImage but it doesn't work.
Any help? Thanks in advice.

I think the AppImage is merely a way to install the package. The actual work is still done by a Linux executable that you should be able to find (using ps) and kill.

AppImage is a packaging format, so the MIDI emulator, like every binary executed in Linux, is a process, and you should kill it.

thanks, but the question is that all PSs changes in every system launch (I suposse), and I need to kill the app without a previous PS check

with pkill
pkill --full -i <regex> (send SIGTERM to all regex matches).
Here, you just need the well-known name of the app, you don't have to know regex syntax, e.g. joplin will match @joplinapp-desktop). But do NOT include "AppImage" in the name.
with killall
(see below for killall --regexp)
You have to use ps once, to find the process name that never changes, and that you need for killall.
ps -ef | grep -i MT-32_Emulator
You need the process name on a line starting with /tmp/.mount_.../path/NAME
With this name, you can killall name. You don't need sudo.
killall accepts 2 forms :

this full process name (consistent with cat /proc/pid/comm (where pid is from the ps line above), which is the common name)
or the short name of this process, with exactly 15 characters

edit : With ps -e | grep -i <name>, you get the 2 short names directly, you choose the one without .AppImage.
underlying cause ?
Strangely, sending SIGTERM to my test Name.AppImage process via htop does terminate the whole app.
Like you noticed, killall doesn't. You have to target the processes from the mountpoint.
The problem is, the processes from the mountpoint are not children of the Name.AppImage process. So when the app exits cleanly, it seems to be more more of a umount operation.
So killall must work in mysterious ways. The manual does say that by default it sends the SIGTERM signal. But I read on the web that sometimes you have to use killall's namespace option --ns 0, but it doesn't work here. I don't know why only htop's SIGTERM can terminate all the processes by targetting the one outside the mount point. But I know sudo does not matter.
killall --process-group doesn't work either.
killall --regexp
killall --regexp <name> where you remove "AppImage" from <name>, only the short name of the app.
if you're curious
You can't look at the files inside an AppImage's /tmp/.mount mount. But you can take a look with a temporary read-only mount,
(in the folder with your AppImage) ./MyApp.AppImage --appimage-mount
This prints the read-only mount point in /tmp/, where you can take a look.
